# Using RPC for Creating a chat Sample Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity ,
I am trying to buid a chat functionality using RPC for Unity.

If one of my device(in which app is installed) is become server and other deivces connect to it, It work fine.

But i want my server to be different machine, in which app is not installed. 
I want my all devices to connect to that server.

How should i configure my server such that i can connect to it for a RPC call.

Comment: Hmm, Well if the App is not Installed. What kind of approach will you have in the Machine, you mentioned RPC. First, you have to make an RPC set up on the Machine. I hope it is not an mobile device that is connected to a router by Wifi. Because it is impossible. The Hacky way is to use a hotspot hosting and make them connect to you, which is dumb.

Comment: @Aizen I am trying to connect to my server from mobile for such that my server can broadcast message to all connected devices